# Textarea with keyword tags in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, textarea

Is it possible to have a `textarea` that allows plain text, but turns certain keywords into "Chips" (or some other styled equivalent)? Ideally I would be able to do this with Angular Material, but I'd be willing to use another library compatible with Angular too. I've done a lot of searching and can't find what I'm looking for.

The "Chips with input" and "Chips with autocomplete" examples here are similar to what I want, but doesn't seem to allow plain text:
https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples

Comment: Take a look at [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with some workaround:

You display a `<div [innerHTML]="formatedCode">` with the formated text inside

When you click on it, you display instead the `<text-area [value]="formatedCode">` so the user can modify the content.

When the user is done, you map the content to the formated code you want. and display the `<div>`